# Laravel - MySQL - Timestamp performance vs boolean column?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization, sql-timestamp

I'm currently running different queries where I want to exclude those users that have not been active for the last 36 hours.

My users table has a `last_connection_time`, which is a timestamp with the last time that the user connected.

I was thinking about adding a `users.last_connection_time < $timestamp_36hours_ago` to the relevant queries.

I'm a bit concerned though about how much may this influence the performance.

Would it be better to run a script every 2 - 6 hours that updates a boolean column in the users table called `inactive` and then simply ignore those inactive users in the query via a `whereNull('users.inactive')`?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing `last_connection_time` and then performing greater / lower than comparisons will be fast enough and an index would be used, that will help MySQL immensely when looking for records.

However, if you create a boolean column and then perform queries based on `whereNull(users.inactive)` -> index cannot help you there, it's a low-cardinality column and MySQL might ignore the index here because it won't help to reduce I/O, thus inspecting the whole dataset - and that's what you want to avoid.

Your data-set probably doesn't exceed terabyte limit (or even a gigabyte), so you probably won't see too many differences between both approaches currently, but for ever-growing dataset I'd simply keep the timestamp column indexed and do `>` or `<` types of queries like you wanted to do in the first scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I should basically add an index flag to the last_connection_time and play with it

Comment: @InigoEC - exactly.